# image.onload() or image.addEventListener() not working in Safari, any solutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, closures, onload-event

I am trying to make it work for the past 2 days, went through every article that I came across regarding this issue but I just can't seem to make it work in Safari. The code works flawlessly in Firefox and Chrome but when I test it in Safari, it always disappoints me. I am trying to do the following:

```
for (var j = 0; j < total_reports; j++) {
        var svgString = $(elem_graph).find('svg');
        $(svgString)[0].setAttribute('width','2500');
        $(svgString)[0].setAttribute('height','500');
        $(svgString)[0].setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 1000 200');
        $(svgString)[0].setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');


        $(elem_graph).find("span").html();
        var img = new Image();
        var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
        var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

        var svgString = $(elem_graph).find('svg');
        $(svgString)[0].setAttribute('width','2500');
        $(svgString)[0].setAttribute('height','500');
        $(svgString)[0].setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 1000 200');
        $(svgString)[0].setAttribute('preserveAspectRatio', 'none');
        svgString=$(elem_graph).find("span").html();

        var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
        var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
        img.onload = (function(img) {
            return function() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                pdf.addImage(png, 'PNG', 10, 120, 485, 270);
                pdf.addPage();
                DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
                pdf.save("test.pdf");

                img_load_counter++;
                canvas = null;
                ctx = null;
                png = null;
            }
        })(img);
        img.src = url;
        svgString = null;
    svg=null;
    unformatSvgString = null;
    url=null;
    }
```

It works fine until it reaches "img.onload = (function(img)" it just does not registers the load event for img. I also tried addEventListener() but it doesn't seem to work either.

Also, the closure, "canvas = null;
                    ctx = null;
                    png = null;"  doesn't seem to free any memory at all, any solutions for that are also welcomed.

Comment: have you gone through http://caniuse.com

Comment: um, not exactly. I checked out if safari supports canvas or not but I simply forgot to check the same for the onload() event. I checked it just now and it seems that the version that I have doesn't support it. Any workaround to get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but I hope it helpful for other people.
You can change:

```
    var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
    var svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
```

with:

```
url = "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent( svgString );
```